# Multiple named routes on a single Laravel 5.8 controller action

Tags: php, laravel

I have several categories that I would like named routes for and they are all using the same controller action, so I've grouped them and did what I thought would work, but it doesn't.  If I only have one route, it works, but breaks when I add others.  I am still new to Laravel, so it doesn't surprise me--routing like this seems a bit dirty, but a lot of posts I've found advocate many hard-coded routes.

**web.php**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'categories', 'as' => 'categories.'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'CategoryController@index')->name('categories');
    Route::get('/{category}', 'CategoryController@show')->where('category', 'amusement-rides')->name('amusement-rides');
    Route::get('/{category}', 'CategoryController@show')->where('category', 'arts-and-crafts')->name('arts-and-crafts');
    Route::get('/{category}', 'CategoryController@show')->where('category', 'carnival-booths')->name('carnival-booths');
    Route::get('/{category}', 'CategoryController@show')->where('category', 'carnival-games')->name('carnival-games');
    Route::get('/{category}', 'CategoryController@show')->where('category', 'concession-machine-rental')->name('concession-machine-rental');
    Route::get('/{category}', 'CategoryController@show')->where('category', 'equipment-rentals')->name('equipment-rentals');
    Route::get('/{category}', 'CategoryController@show')->where('category', 'events')->name('events');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your web.php file should like.

**Web.php**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'categories', 'as' => 'categories.'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'CategoryController@index')->name('categories');
    Route::get('/{category}', 'CategoryController@show')->name('show');

});
```

In your browser the URLs called be like.

**URL**

```
http://baseurl/categories/amusement-rides
http://baseurl/categories/arts-and-crafts
http://baseurl/categories/carnival-booths
http://baseurl/categories/carnival-games
http://baseurl/categories/concession-machine-rental
http://baseurl/categories/equipment-rentals
http://baseurl/categories/equipment-rentals
```

finally, If you want to access category name in controller then you may access by using parameter like.

**Controller**

```
public function show($categories){
    echo $categories; //here you'll get amusement-rides, arts-and-crafts, carnival-booths, carnival-games
}
```

Comment: I did know I could did it this way, but I thought I needed to explicitly name the route in order to create a link like `<a href="{{ route('carnival-games' }}">{{$category.name}}</a>`?

Comment: {{ route('categories.show',['category'=>$categoryname]) }}

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-can-i-pass-parameter-in-route-hrefroutetestval-to-blade-view?page=0